NextJS with TS Three Error: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
I'm trying to add a sphere made with three in my NextJS project with TypeScript, I get my page to run when I navigate to the page where the sphere is, but if I reload the page I get the error
Error: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"
file:///D:/repo-rute/repo-name/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js (1)
I understand that it is because in the EffectComposer.js file that was installed in node_modules contains imports which cannot be used outside of a type modules file, this is why I set in my json package "type": "module", but I still get this error.
here is my package.json and then the page where I am trying to put this sphere
// package.json
{
  "name": "aplicationName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "three": "^0.128.0",
    "@types/three": "^0.128.0",

    "@types/node": "20.3.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    
    
    "tsx": "^3.12.7",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.69",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.13",
    "@types/sass": "^1.45.0",
    "@types/three": "^0.128.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.4",
    "three": "^0.128.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "glob-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.72.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

// page
"use client";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import sphere from "@/styles/sphere.module.scss";
import { startApp } from "@/pages/render/cloud";

export default function Home() {

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRefLight = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await startApp(canvasRef.current,canvasRefLight.current))();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <main className={sphere.chat}>
      
      <div className={sphere.mindara__container}>
        <div ref={canvasRef} className={sphere.mindara}></div>
        <div ref={canvasRefLight} className={sphere.mindara__light}></div>
      </div>

    </main>
  );
}


I need the sphere to always display and not show this error.
